Update Multiple Columns AND Rows
Using the CASE expressions, I figured out how to update multiple rows in a SQL table in a single SQL statement, but only one column.  I am trying to figure out how to update multiple rows and multiple columns in each row, if that is even possible.  I keep getting the following SQL error:

This is the value of Err.Number: -2147217900
This is the value of Err.Description: Incorrect syntax near '='.

The following code updates a single column "MemberID" in multiple rows of a single table, based upon the value of each order ID:
    sSQLOrderUpdate = "UPDATE ORDERS_BACKUP " &_
    "SET MemberID = CASE OrderID " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_1 & "' THEN '" & iMemberID & "' " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_2 & "' THEN '" & iMemberID & "' " &_
    "END; " &_
    "WHERE OrderID IN ('" & iOrderID_1 & "','" & iOrderID_2 & "') "

I tried doing something like this to include another column:
    sSQLOrderUpdate = "UPDATE ORDERS_BACKUP " &_
    "SET MemberID = CASE OrderID " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_1 & "' THEN '" & iMemberID & "' " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_2 & "' THEN '" & iMemberID & "' " &_
    "END; " &_
    "SET CustomerID = CASE OrderID " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_1 & "' THEN '" & iCustomerID & "' " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_2 & "' THEN '" & iCustomerID & "' " &_
    "END; " &_
    "WHERE OrderID IN ('" & iOrderID_1 & "','" & iOrderID_2 & "') "

This is the complete built SQL string:
UPDATE ORDERS_BACKUP 
SET MemberID = CASE OrderID 
                   WHEN '80087' THEN '5429' 
                   WHEN '80091' THEN '5429' 
               END
SET CustomerID = CASE OrderID 
                     WHEN '80087' THEN '2050' 
                     WHEN '80091' THEN '2050' 
                 END
WHERE OrderID IN ('80087', '80091') 


Case is not a statement its an expression

It would be much easier for us to assist if you showed us the actual SQL i.e. the result after you've built it.

You look like you have breaking ;s after each case.

As @DaleK mentioned, the semicolon after the END in your CASE expressions is totally wrong. Remove it. Also, when asking SQL questions, post SQL, not some code that does concatenation with values we cannot see and is cluttered with a lot of irrelevant quotation marks.

So if you check the documentation for the UPDATE statement, you will find that 1) you only use the keywork SET once, and 2) you need a comma between each column you update.

Thank you @Dale K.  Removed the 2nd SET, and added the comma, and now it all works!

You have serious SQL injection problems by the way.

@Charlieface Care to explain this in more detail?  I don't think you are correct.

You have things like "WHEN '" & iOrderID_1 & "' THEN '" & iMemberID & "' " which is quite clearly injecting data directly into the query, instead of using parameters. This leaves you open to malicious attacks (imagine someone putting '; DELETE FROM Users -- as one of the parameters), and incorrect syntax (if you don't escape properly), and no query plan caching (this applies even if all parameters are integers). There shouldn't be a "built SQL string", there should be only one possible SQL string with proper parameters.

You should not be terminating the query with a semicolon ; after each update expression, a simple comma , can be used to delimit the column expressions:
Also note the SET keyword is used to define the start of the column expressions, it is used only once in the query.
 sSQLOrderUpdate = "UPDATE ORDERS_BACKUP " &_
    "SET MemberID = CASE OrderID " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_1 & "' THEN '" & iMemberID & "' " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_2 & "' THEN '" & iMemberID & "' " &_
    "END, " &_
    "CustomerID = CASE OrderID " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_1 & "' THEN '" & iCustomerID & "' " &_
    "WHEN '" & iOrderID_2 & "' THEN '" & iCustomerID & "' " &_
    "END " &_
    "WHERE OrderID IN ('" & iOrderID_1 & "','" & iOrderID_2 & "') "


You must sanitize all inputs before using an expression like this, this type of query where you concatenate in runtime variable values is highly susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.


Code Review:
While this query might work for your logic, it is not a typical scenario to use a CASE expression within an UPDATE. When there are multiple conditions that set the same value for a column, but you filter the result set to just the rows that will be affected, then you don't really need CASE at all, the following SQL should produce the same result:
UPDATE ORDERS_BACKUP SET
  MemberID = @memberId
 , CustomerID = @customerId
WHERE OrderID IN (@orderId1, @OrderId2)


Thank you very much.  I'll try that.  I am still learning the SQL syntax, so really do appreciate the help.

And thank you also for pointing out that the variables must be sanitized.  This code is part of an administration area of a website that isn't accessible to anyone but 1 person, and the data is not coming from a form.  It's just a utility for cleaning up member logins.

That doesn't excuse poor practises ;) you are here to learn, so look into how you can use parameterised queries so that you do not develop bad practises. I have to put that disclaimer in there because I don't want anyone reading at home to think that this is an example of the right way to do things. Also have a read about OWASP Top 10, there is a lot to learn but those are the minimum standards your work should always adhere to.

From the string concatenation, OP appears to be using a variant of Visual Basic. Maybe VBA or VB.Net? Both have documented libraries and many StackOverflow posts for SQL parameterization.
